# oAuth2 Access Token with userinfo

Tags: spring, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

We have a little argument in the company on the way to get user info with oAuth2.

the first developer is getting the user info inside the access token with the library `spring-security-oauth2` and decode it.

The second developer use open id connect on the top of the oAuth2 with the library `Nimbus`, In this way you will get the user info from UserInfo Endpoint.

Which way is better parctice? and why to use open id connect if I can get my userinfo without this

Thanks for any help and explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An access token - and in fact bare OAuth 2.0 - cannot be used to authenticate the user. It can only be used to retrieve information about a user, which may not be the user that is operating the browser. See: https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/

So if you want to authenticate the user - in a standards compliant way - you need to use OpenID Connect.

Comment: Thanks man! I thought that oAuth2 is authentication protocol, Shame on me.